delete[] isn't deleting the arrays
I'm building a class that's a Matrix. To do so I built a array of double pointer. So I'm trying to implement a destructor for this class Matrix but the delete[] isn't operating as expected
Here is the code:
Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c):rowsM(r), colsM(c)
{
    matrixM = new double* [rowsM];
    assert(matrixM != NULL);
    
    for(int i=0; i < rowsM; i++){
        matrixM[i] = new double[colsM];
        assert(matrixM[i] != NULL);
    }
    sum_rowsM = new double[rowsM];
    assert(sum_rowsM != NULL);
    
    sum_colsM = new double[colsM];
    assert(sum_colsM != NULL);
}

void Matrix::destroy()
{   
    for(int i=0; i < rowsM; i++){
        delete[] matrixM[i];
        assert(matrixM[i] == NULL);
    }
    
    delete[] matrixM;
    assert(matrixM != NULL);
    
    delete[] sum_rowsM;
    assert(sum_rowsM == NULL);
    
    delete[] sum_colsM;
    assert(sum_colsM == NULL);
}


I've tried working with delete without success so I looked it up and figured that delete[] was the better choice but the outcome on Cygwin (that I use to compile) is that
assertion "matrixM[i] == NULL" failed: file "matrix.cpp", function: void Matrix::destroy()
    Aborted

meaning that the delete clearly failed. pls send help

An array of pointers is the worst possible way how to represent a dense matrix; please, don't do that. Also note that at the "application programming level", you should completely avoid using new and delete in the code.

Whatever it is that you're learning from is not a reliable source. Get yourself a good book.

There are good reasons to learn about using arrays of pointers, new and delete and such and a matrix class is a good one for teaching this. But any instruction in this should be followed up by why this has awful performance and should not be used since the 80's.

Your understanding of new/new[] and delete/delete[] is incorrect, and all the assert calls in your code should be removed.
Firstly new and new[] never return NULL on failure. If they fail they throw a std::bad_alloc exception.
Secondly delete and delete[] do not modify their arguments. Specifically they do not set the argument to NULL.
Apart from the issues with assert your code is correct (as far as one can tell from what has been posted).

for the record https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow can be used to   avoid exception and test for nullptr instead

"do not modify their arguments": In practice yes, however (almost) any use of the (then invalid) pointer value has implementation-defined behavior. An implementation would be allowed to set the pointers implicitly to null pointer values. (I am not aware of any implementation doing that.)

"Apart from the issues with assert your code is correct": (And apart from exception-safety, for the reason you mentioned. And this is a major reason never to use raw new/delete.)

perhaps worth mentioning that there is also no other portable way to check if delete did actually delete an array of integers. Any attempt to see if there still is an array would invoke ub.
